# Cannot work out how to access property of self in ViewModel

Tags: javascript, c#, html, knockout.js

I am very new to js and html - trying to make a basic front end for a C# web api.

I'm making a simple app for tracking bugs. I have a panel for the list of bugs, where I can click "Details" to see more info on each bug (I would post an image, but my reputation is too low). Then a new panel opens with with the details of the bug, including a button to close the bug, ie change set the status to "closed". It's with this button that I have the problem.

I have this in my Index.cshtml:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Bugs</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: bugs">
                <li>
                    <strong><span data-bind="text: Title"></span></strong>: <span data-bind="text: Description"></span>
                    <small><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.getBugDetail">Details</a></small>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error"><p data-bind="text: error">
</p></div>

<!-- ko if:detail() -->
    @* Bug Detail with Close Button *@
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Detail</h2>
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <tr><td>Title</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Title"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Description</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Description"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Status</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Status"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Created</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Created"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Owner</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Owner"></td></tr>
            </table>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: closeBug(detail())">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Close bug</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /ko -->
```

Then this is the relevant stuff in app.js:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.bugs = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.detail = ko.observable();

    self.getBugDetail = function (item) {
        ajaxHelper(bugsUri + item.Id, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.detail(data);
        });
    }

    var bugsUri = '/api/bugs/';

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error(''); // Clear error message
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    // get open bugs
    function getAllBugs() {
        ajaxHelper(bugsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.bugs(data);
        });
    }

    // Fetch the initial data.
    getAllBugs();

    //close bug
    self.closeBug = function (localDetail) {

        var closedBug = {
            OwnerId: self.localDetail.OwnerId,
            Description: self.localDetail.Description,
            Status: "closed",
            Title: self.localDetail.Title,
            Created: self.localDetail.Created
        };

        ajaxHelper(bugsUri + self.localDetail.Id, 'DELETE', self.localDetail.Id);

        ajaxHelper(bugsUri, 'POST', closedBug).done(function (item) {
            self.bugs.push(item);
        });
    }

};
```

To update the status of a bug, I want to take the Id of the bug currently open in the detail panel and create an identical bug except with `Status` set to "closed". The trouble is that there's always a problem access `self.localDetail` in the new variable `closedBug`. I've tried it here by parameterizing the `closeBug` method, but I've also tried accessing `self.Detail`, but it's done no good, so I'm here. My next step, if this fails, is to create a separate panel entirely with a form for `bugId` which closes the bug when you submit, but it would be better to be in the bug details window.

Answer (score 0):

you're already passing `localDetail` as the param in the `closeBug` fn, so you don't need  to refer to it by adding `self.` Try  this (removed all references to `self.`):

```
//close bug
self.closeBug = function (localDetail) {

    var closedBug = {
        OwnerId: localDetail.OwnerId,
        Description: localDetail.Description,
        Status: "closed",
        Title: localDetail.Title,
        Created: localDetail.Created
    };

    ajaxHelper(bugsUri + localDetail.Id, 'DELETE', localDetail.Id);

    ajaxHelper(bugsUri, 'POST', closedBug).done(function (item) {
        self.bugs.push(item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is in your `submit` binding itself. It's being called as soon as it's rendered, *not* on submit. You want to pass the function object (optionally with bound arguments) instead of calling it in your html.

### Explicit Bound Arguments

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: closeBug.bind(null, detail)">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Close bug</button>
</form>
```

which will bind `null` as the `this` value of the function and pass the `detail` observable as the first argument. With this, your `closeBug` looks like

```js
self.closeBug = function (localDetail) {
  var closedBug = {
    OwnerId: localDetail().OwnerId
  }
}
```

Note, you want to unwrap it in the handler, not the html so you get the latest value and not the initial value.

#### Binding Context as `this`

Alternatively (and in more idiomatic knockout fashion) you can bind to the function object and it will be called with the binding context as `this` (the same as explicitly using `closeBug.bind($data)`).

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: closeBug">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Close bug</button>
</form>
```

```js
self.closeBug = function () {
  var closedBug = {
    OwnerId: this.localDetail().OwnerId
  }
}
```

---

Aside: [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-this-keyword-binding-rules/) may be helpful for better understanding `this`, `self`, and `function.bind`